# How to get the first value of multiple arrays and store it in another array in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4jclient, cypher-3.1

I do have values like

```
first  = [1, 2]
second = [2, 3]
third  = [1, 3]
```

and I want to have `[1,2,1]` in neo4j?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH [1,2] AS first, [2,3] AS second, [1,3] AS third
RETURN [first[0]] + [second[0]] + [third[0]]
```

As a more generic/more elegant solution, you can also use a [list comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension):

```
WITH [1,2] AS first, [2,3] AS second, [1,3] AS third
RETURN [list IN [first, second, third] | list[0]]
```